# Why is my php trim() function not working?

Tags: php, trim

I'm trying to use trim to remove the underline character from the data that is returned in the $_POST array.  I tried using

```
 $post_Value= str_replace("_", " ", $key)
```

but the text does not seem to return as one single string.  It's broken between each entry. Then I tried trim like this:

```
   $post_Value = trim("_", $str);
```

When I use the trim function nothing happens it does not remove the `_` character.  My eventual goal is to put a comma delimited list in my database as a single string.  Why would my `trim()` function not work in this case?

Comment: If you want to remove underscore, you can use `str_replace()`, but second paramter should be an empty string, so it should look like: `str_replace("_", "", $key) `.

Comment: Can you share sample input data where this is not working? Also, be warned that your `UPDATE`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim)? Its second argument is not a fragment to be trimmed but a list of characters to be trimmed. `rtrim($post_Value2,",submit,")` does not remove the word `",submit,"` from the right side of `$post_Value2`, it removes the characters `,`, `b`, `i`, `m`, `s`, `t` and `u`, no matter in what order they appear on the right side of the string.

Comment: _"My eventual goal is to put a comma delimited list in my database as a single string."_ -- Don't store IDs joined by comma in a text column. That is a relationship between two entities. Use a separate table for that.

Answer (score 4):

First, `trim()` takes *arguments in the opposite order*: `$str`, then `$character_mask`. So you should have used: `$post_Value = trim($str, "_");`

Second, `trim()` strings the masked characters *only from the beginning and end* of the string. It doesn't remove any masked characters from the string if they are surrounded by non-masked characters.

---

You should actually use *`str_replace()` with an empty replacement string* (you've tried a single space as replacement):

```
$post_Value= str_replace("_", "", $key)
```

If you also want to remove `<br>` tags (in its typical variations), you may do so via single `str_replace()` call, as follows:

```
$post_Value= str_replace(array("_", "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />"), "", $key)
```

See [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) docs for details.

Comment: I switched the parameters and got each entry on a new line instead being a single string.

Comment: I found some <br/> when I viewed the page resource.  I don't have them in my code so this is confusing.  I finally had to do a combination of str_replace() and rtrim() like this:      $post_Value= str_replace("<br_/>", "", $str);
   $post_Value2= str_replace("_", " ", $post_Value);
   $post_Value3= rtrim($post_Value2,",submit,");
   echo $post_Value3;
   //echo $editedStr=str_replace("_", " ", $str);
   
   $query="UPDATE player_match SET categoryOption='$post_Value3' WHERE id=1";

Answer (score 0):

I found some 
 when I viewed the page resource. I don't have them in my code so this is confusing. I finally had to do a combination of str_replace() and rtrim() like this:

```
 $post_Value= str_replace("<br_/>", "", $str); $post_Value2= str_replace("", " ", $post_Value); $post_Value3= rtrim($post_Value2,",submit,"); echo $post_Value3; //echo $editedStr=str_replace("", " ", $str); $query="UPDATE player_match SET categoryOption='$post_Value3' WHERE id=1";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_replace( '/^\W*(.*?)\W*$/', '$1', $string )

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
    \W*                    non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0- 9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
    (                      group and capture to \1:
      .*?                  any character except \n (0 or more times(matching the least amount possible))
    )                      end of \1
    \W*                    non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```